PyEnv in WSL2 requires a lot of using apk versions of packages and rebuilding
I'm currently doing most of my development work in WSL2 and since I use python a lot for different projects I started using pyenv to keep my python versions and virtualenvironments clean and seperated. But I've been experiencing a lot of issues when it comes to installing packages. Normally I would always only use pip inside a virtualenv to make sure that a package is only installed in that virtualenvironment, but for some packages this leads to an unfinished or uncomplete install of that package.
Installing jupyter for example and using it in VSCode lead to
Import Error: No module names _sqlite3

Following the advice in this discussion I installed the respective linux package for sqlite and then had to remove my python version from pyenv and reinstall/rebuild it.
And I had similar problems now, dealing with rather "normal" python packages, like matplotlib. After several reinstalls using pip and restarting the kernel, I went back to installing it using sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib and then had to completely reinstall the respective python version, which also includes setting up the virtualenv again.
Does anyone have experiences with these issues and knows a better work-around than rebuilding everytime I need a python package?
